# many-to-many select with complex condition

Tags: sql, select, many-to-many

I have the tables:

```
+------------+
| Ingredient |
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+
| name       |
+------------+

+---------------+
| Relingredient |
+---------------+
| id_ingredient |
+---------------+
| id_recipe     |
+---------------+

+--------+
| Recipe |
+--------+
| id     |
+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
```

---

And **I need to Select Recipes that have the ingredients that I want** (ALL the ingredients pass to them) I tried this:

```
SELECT R.id, R.nom FROM Recipe R, Relingredient RI, Ingredient I 
WHERE  R.id = RI.id_recipe AND RI.id_ingredient = I.id AND I.name='onion' AND I.name='oil' 
GROUP BY R.name
```

but retuns zero rows

I also tried this:

```
SELECT R.id, R.nom FROM Recipe R, Relingredient RI, Ingredient I 
WHERE  R.id = RI.id_recipe AND RI.id_ingredient = I.id AND (I.name='onion' or I.name='oil') 
GROUP BY R.name
```

But it selects all recipes that have onion or oil, not only the ones wich haves onion **AND** oil ... What can I do?

(edit) sample of what I want: 
for example I have the recipes:
1: grilled chicken(ingredients: chicken, onion, oil)
2: chinese soup(ingredients: pork, onion, oil, noodles)
3: vegetable sandwich (ingredients: bread, oil, tomato, salad)
**The query should return just the recipes: grilled chicken and chinese soup**

Thanks for Helping me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
  R.id, R.name
FROM Recipt R
  JOIN Relingredient RI
    ON R.Id = RI.Id_recipe
  JOIN Ingredient I
    ON RI.Id_ingredient = I.Id
WHERE I.name = 'onion'
    OR I.name='oil'
GROUP BY R.id, R.name
HAVING COUNT(I.name) = 2
```

Comment: It don't worked, but thanks, the ingredients can be more than the ones wich I search, I want to select recipes that contain ingredients I search.

Comment: @user3671561 Don't work, it is not explanation of problem. Be more specific. This query exactly returns all recipe which contains onion and oil.

Comment: it also returned to me one recipe that only have oil, not the both oil+onion

Comment: Thanks sir! I tried again and it worked! I don't know if last time I copied it bad or what, the fact is that now works well, I tested many times and seems that works nice

Comment: @MikeRamos, it can be only case when you have attached oil to recipe two times. If it is option, you can use COUNT(DISTINCT I.Name) instead of.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT R.id, R.name FROM Recipe R
       Where R.Id in (
                         Select RI.Id_recipe From Relingredient as RI 
                                INNER JOIN Ingredient as I ON  RI.Id_ingredient = I.Id
                                WHERE I.name = 'onion'
                                      OR I.name='oil'
                     )
```

I got it completely. 
New query:

```
SELECT  *
        FROM    dbo.Recipt
        WHERE   Id IN ( SELECT  id_recipe
            FROM    dbo.Relingredient
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Ingredient ON id_ingredient = Id
            WHERE   Name = 'oil' )
    AND Id IN ( SELECT  id_recipe
                FROM    dbo.Relingredient
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Ingredient ON id_ingredient = Id
                WHERE   Name = 'union' )
```

Comment: It don't worked, It returned me recipes that have onion or oil not the ones that contain both ingredients but thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you write a sample data to explain exactly what you want?

Comment: Dear Mike, I created your sample, that answer is not correct for YOUR QUESTION!!!! My query is correct!!!

Answer (score 0):

To get exactly the ingredients you are looking for, use a `having` clause:

```
SELECT R.id, R.nom
FROM Recipe R JOIN
     Relingredient RI
     ON R.id = RI.id_recipe JOIN
     Ingredient I 
     ON RI.id_ingredient = I.id
GROUP BY R.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN I.name = 'onion' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN I.name = 'oil' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN I.name NOT IN ('onion', 'oil') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause checks one of the conditions.  The first checks that at least one ingredient is "onion", the second that at least one is "oil", and the third that no other ingredients are present.  Remove the last clause if you want to allow other ingredients.

This method is quite flexible for different conditions on the ingredients.

EDIT:

The following `having` clause lets you name the ingredients only once.  But you need to also insert the count:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN I.name IN ('onion', 'oil') THEN I.name END) = COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) AND
       COUNT(DISTINCT NAME) = 2;
```

The `distinct` is in case one recipe can include an ingredient more than once.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . A line that should have been deleted.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your time but seems that somehting dont work, it returns me:
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0028 sec )